# How to pull from many repos with tortoisegit?

Tags: git, tortoisegit, git-pull

I have many different repos residing in the same directory (about 20). I would like to stay up-to-date with the rest of my team and perform a "git pull" for all of the repos at every morning.

Is there a faster way than doing a "right-click -> git sync -> pull" for every single repo?

Comment: Should create a new feature request. But I bet there is something systemic with the way it integrates with explorer that makes it not possible.

Answer (score 3):

No, as of TortoiseGit 1.8.5. You have to pull all repositories many times.

But you can suggest this as an enhancement in [TortoiseGit](https://tortoisegit.org/issues)'s issue tracker.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my script to sync all repositories within a folder:

```
@echo off
pushd %~dp0
for /d %%d in ("*") do (
  pushd %%d
  if exist ".git" tortoisegitproc /command:sync /closeonend:1
  popd
)
popd
```

Given a directory structure like this:

- /

  - tortoise-sync-all.cmd
  - repo1/
  - repo2/

tortoise-sync-all will iterate through all subdirectories which have a .git folder inside, and issue the sync command one after another.

Answer (score 1):

If your team's repos are all forks of a single canonical repo, and your local repo is another clone, then just add each team member's fork as a remote, then use `git fetch` with the `--all` flag from the command line:

```
git remote add coworker1 <fork-url>
git remote add coworker2 <fork-url>
# ...
git fetch --all
```

You might be able to fetch all of the remotes using TortoiseGit too, but I'm not sure.

Comment: I think the asker had about 20 local repositories under one directory. Not  one local repository which manager 20 remote repositories. So `git fetch --all` does not work for this question. And yes, TortoiseGit can do fetch all of remotes.

Answer (score 0):

As of TortoiseGit 2.12.0 you can select several folders and right-click to choose "Git Pull .." - this will run the "Git Pull" dialog for all the folders in succession.